# Prove/Provide counter-example: complex function is a. not entire b. continuous

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an entire complex function that is non-constant. We define $g : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as follows:

$g(z)=
\begin{cases}
 1&\text{if}\, f(z)=0\\
 \frac{|f(z)|+1}{|f(z)|}.f(z) &\text{if}\, f(z)\neq0\     
\end{cases}$

Prove/ provide a counter example that the function $g(z)$ is a. not entire b. continuous in $\mathbb{C}$.

Since $f$ is entire and non-constant I conluded that $f$ is not bounded from Liouville's theorem, I believe $g$ is not entire and non-continuous. How do I go about proving both?
Thank you.

Comment: Your Question formulation seems a little scrambled.  Are there two problems here?  The use of (a) and (b) in the title but not the body makes me suspect that.  Or perhaps you want an answer about whether $g$ could be both continuous and not entire?

Comment: Sorry I'll fix it right away, yes there are two problems.

Comment: I think there is a need to further improve the problem statements.  The body of a Question allows you space to write complete sentences, so shortening and abbreviating the problem statements with "shared phrasing" has little advantage and invites ambiguity.  Obviously a function that is not continuous cannot be entire, so I recommend giving both parts of the Question separate statements, followed by your observations which connect them.  If there is not a substantial connection between the two parts of the problem (beyond some shared setup), then posting both together is discouraged.

Comment: Someone else asked the exact same question few hours before you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4151210/entire-function-on-the-complex-plane-and-minimum-modulus-principle-theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) It cannot be entire. *Hint.* Show that these functions are not complex-differentiable at points where $f(z) \neq 0$:
$$
h_1(z) = |f(z)|, \quad h_2(z) = \frac{|f(z)|+1}{|f(z)|}, \quad h_3(z) = \frac{|f(z)|+1}{|f(z)|} f(z).
$$
You may want to start with $h_1$ ([open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) should help, although there are easier ways), then express $h_1$ in terms of $h_2$ and $h_2$ in terms of $h_3$.

b) The function $f(z) = z$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you, and because the function $f$ is not given in a $x+iy$ form I assume I can't use the Cauchy–Riemann equations to prove complex-differentiability. Is there something I must conclude from the given information about the differentiability of the function $f$ ?

Comment: Right, so differentiability of $f$ should tell you that $|f|$ is not (complex) differentiable. This follows from the open mapping theorem. If you like to avoid this theorem, you can work at a point where $f(z) \neq 0$ and $f'(z) \neq 0$ and check directly that $|f(z)|$ is not differentiable (e.g. by Cauchy-Riemann equations!).

Answer (score 0):

If $f(z)=z$, then you can check easily that
$$\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 0 \\ \alpha >0}g(i\alpha) = i \neq 1 =g(0)$$

so $g$ is not continuous.